# How to attach a addShutdownHook() in a multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following program structure

My Main.java

```
public class Main
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        int totalNumberOfThreads = 0;
        Thread newThread = null;

        try
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Starting autorsponder!");
                    newThread = new Thread(new AutoresponderHtml());

                    UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex)
                        {
                            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                            try
                            {
                                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("throwable.txt"), true);
                            }
                            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
                            ex.printStackTrace(ps);
                        }
                    };

                    newThread.setName(threadName);
                    newThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
                    newThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Main ended");

    }
}
```

My AutoresponderHtml.java class

```
public class AutoresponderHtml extends Common implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    }
}
```

How would I attach a addShutdownHook() to every thread that starts?

Comment: addShutdownHook() runs the hook when the JVM shuts down - is that what you actually want(And if so, what do you want to do that's specific to each of your threads ?), or do you want to run a hook when the thread is finished ?

Comment: addShutdownHook doesn't works for threads.

Comment: If the file `throwable.txt` is not found your `UncaughtExceptionHandler` will fail with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I need to add it so when I press ctrl-c on the console I can make some releasing of resources

Comment: @Arya for example see the link http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.sg/2010/11/runtimeaddshutdownhook.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to attach a ShutdownHook to every thread you start, especially because it is not possible. Due to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but unstarted thread. When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently.

It is just one more Thread wich is started, while JVM is shutting down. Sure, you can make as much shutdownhooks, as you wish, but they all will be waiting for JVM shutdon and it could not the behaviour you need. If you still need it to be run, then just get the Runtime and register a new thread:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
         //your logic here
    }
});
```

But if you need some logic to be running after some thread has finished execution, then you need some other solution. May be even simple try-finally in thread implementation.

And furthermore, don't rely too much on it, your JVM could be stopped without shutdownhook is get executed. And even more, it doesn't really freez a JVM shutdowm process, that means, that your JVM can be stopped with not finished shutdownhook ligic.